# Dynamic og:image for Facebook share button

Tags: javascript, facebook

Similar to this [medium article](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fs%2Funrulybodies%2Fthe-body-my-immigrant-parents-may-never-understand-c6aea51091ab) where a custom og:image, og:title, and og:description are displayed for different articles, when the facebook share button is clicked a popup opens to let the user type a message and below is the image/title/description grabbed from meta tags (og:image, og:title, etc)

When the user clicks on the facebook share button I then dynamically change the meta tags to customized images/descriptions using javascript like so

```
document.head.querySelector("[property='og:image']").setAttribute("content", image_url)
```

the problem is that the image isn't appearing at all when the fb share button is clicked - when I enter the url into Sharing debugger it works, but on the actual website it doesn't

Comment: Facebook doesn't execute Javascript when they scrape you. You need to give Facebook a unique URL that contains the og:image you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not certain what your aim is but you won't be able to set the og:image using Javascript because facebook is getting the image url etc. from the HTML returned by the url when its own server requests that url. It's not getting that data from the client.